# load data to grid in angular 6 using http get

Tags: jqgrid, angular6

Im trying to load the following sample data to jqgrid(free) using `http.get` in angular 6.

```
[{"maker":"Toyota", "model":"Celica"},{ "maker": "Chrysler", "model":"Mondeo"}]
```

Model Class

```
export class Model{ 
    maker : string
    model : string
}
```

Component:

```
...
@Component({...})
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
   private _sampleService;

  columnModel : any[];
  models : Model[];

  constructor(_sampleService : SampleService) {
        this._sampleService = _sampleService;
   }
   ngOnInit() {
      this.columnModel = [{ name: "maker" },{ name: "model" }]
      this.models = this._sampleService.getModelList().subscribe(models => this.models = models);
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    (<any>jQuery("#grid")).jqGrid({
        colModel: this.columnModel,
        data: this.models
    });
  }
}
```

Service:

```
....
@Injectable()
export class SampleService{
 constructor(private http : HttpClient){}

 getModelList():Observable<Model[]>{
   return this.http.get<Model[]> 
  ("http://localhost:8090/myapp/getModel");
 }
}
```

If I do the following, I can see the data in the console.

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:8090/ducksoup/getModel")
 .subscribe(data => {console.log(data)})
```

But,it is not rendering in the grid. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your jqxGrid binding code inside of OnInit method, right after you fetch your records and it will show your data on datagrid